# Remove old vCenter servers from VMWare vSphere Client login window

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vsphere-client, vmware-vcenter

After changing our vCenter servers recently, the old vCenter server is still listed in the VMWare vSphere Client login dialog in the IP Address / Name: drop down. Is there a way to remove the old/invalid entries from this dropdown?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That list is stored in a Registry key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\VMware\VMware Infrastructure Client\Preferences\RecentConnections`.

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&externalId=1032988

Comment: That was it. I'd been looking around there but not at that particular key. Thank you.

Comment: Found the registry key, and deleted it, but it still appears in dropdown.  Does computer require a reboot?

Answer (score 3):

They're saved in a registry key but the exact path varies based on VSClient version, just do a search on the vCenter server name in regedit, there's probably little other reason for that string to be in there.